# Ubuntu Server 16.04: how to setup my /etc/network/interface to prefer the 5ghz connection?

Tags: 16.04, networking, server

so I have an Ubuntu server 16.04 box here. I'm testing using wireless connection since my cabling between the 2 house sections (where my router is and the server) is not the greatest.

**My question is:**

how can I set /etc/network/interfaces so it prefers to use the 5GHz hardware of my dual-band WiFi card?

Thanks

Comment: The question is unclear. You can easily set different SSIDs for 5 GHz and 2.4 GHz networks and select the one you like.

Comment: I've read in smallnetbuilder that it's best to have the same SSID for both 5 and 2Ghz channels. :)

Comment: It is not "the best", it is a very bad idea.

Comment: not sure what your qualifications are but the people in smallnetbuilder seems to know that stuff when it comes to home networking :)

Comment: but let's stick to topic please. Thanks